# Why are feral cats slowly blinking back at me?

Tags: cats, behavior

I read that slow blinking is a sign of relaxation. Since most feral cats are afraid of humans, I slowly blink at them. I have noticed that many cats return this slow blink at me.

Why are they returning the slow blink? Does this mean I can go near a feral after slowly blinking at them? I have never tried to go near them after slowly blinking.

Edit: The question I mentioned - [Is blinking slowly at cats a way to tell them that you love them?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2281/10293)

Answer (score 4):

The slow blink is a cat's way to tell other cats I do not want to fight you.

So it is a way for cats to avoid trouble before it starts. If two cats meet and only one of them blinks the one blinking will retreat as this shows the cat not slow blinking will fight or protect its territory.

So the slow blink is to tell the other cat I am not hostile.
This is the same if you slow blink to a cat, you tell the cat I am not hostile. If the cat blinks back you both have a deal in not being unfriendly.

So this is not an invitation to come closer to the cat even if this is often possible.

In this situation let the cat come to you. If you try to approach the cat it will feel like prey and run away.

We people have the same type of non verbal communication we do often smile to unknown people we meet because we are unsure about the person. If the person smiles back it gives a signal of not being unfriendly.

Comment: Except we the people can fake a smile xD

Comment: you are right we can and we do and it is helpful too if we wants to interract with a person,but i think cats are unable to fake a slow blink even if they are masters of manipulation :)

Comment: @trondhansen A TV pet expert Jackson Galaxy advocates what you wrote as well. He even takes off his glasses and slow blinks at a cat he is working with and waits for them to slow blink back. Personally i just think slow blinks mean the cat is relaxed, and it is not a conscious form of communication - more like cat body language.